# KAFKA REMOTE AWS consumer.poll

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, consumer, producer

Hi I have been trying to learn KAFKA and having issues with my remote poller/consumer.

I have set up KAFKA in AWS EC2 instance with private and public ip. my server.properties looks like this.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.31.31.58:9092  #AWS Private IP

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://35.??.??.??:9092 #AWS Public IP Masked
```

My AWS EC2 security group is configured to allow traffic over any ip on any port for testing purposes.

When I produce/consume messages locally with in my EC2 instance using following scripts it works perfectly

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

But when I try to connect to same kafka instance from my remote laptop Eclipse code running my java API, my code hangs for ever in consumer.poll(100). Am I doing some thing wrong here?

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "35.??.??.??:9092");//my aws public ip configured in advertised.listeners
props.put("group.id", "test123");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

     }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the log file for your consumer? It would be helpful to see the debug messages.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it hangs in `poll()` ? or is `poll()` just returning an empty `ConsumerRecords` and it's looping in the `while(true)` ?

By default, if you've not committed any offsets for the group, the consumer starts at the end of the topic, so it will only receive new messages. In that case, if you want to consume messages already in the topic, you need to set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` (like you did in the console-consumer with `--from-beginning`)

Edit:

If it's actually stuck in `poll()`, it could be a connection issue. To find out, the best way is to run your client with logging enabled. Create a file containing:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

and start your client with `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:PATH_TO_FILE`

Comment: Yes Mickael, It hangs in poll, basically it does not move on to the next line, I have verified this.

Comment: Hi Mickael, this definetly is a network issue. I tried this earlier in my office network and it did not work and works perfectly in a different network. Infact I ran my program with debug log enabled as per your suggestion and nothing was logged that suggested any network issue. But this works now in a different network, and your suggestion on network issue lead me to think to run this through different network. Thank you very much.